# React-slick reinit

Tags: reactjs, slick.js

I'm using react-slick slider and can't figure out how I can re-initialize the slider.  With the jquery slick plugin, I can call $slick.reInit(), but using react I can't seem to do this.  Is there something similar I can do in react to the reinit method?

Answer (score 10):

There is no such feature for now, but there is a way to do it.

If you wrap Slick with a component and give it a unique key, slick reloads each time the key changes

```
render: function() {
    return <div key={uniqueId}>
               <CarouselComponent>
           </div>;
}
```